# How to make a signal interrupt sem_wait() but not terminate the process?

Tags: c, signals, semaphore

I am using `sem_wait()` as part of an IPC application, but I want the
wait to be interruptible by ctrl-C, and to continue the program if
this happens. Currently, however, any signal terminates my program.

The `sem_wait` man page says "the `sem_wait()` function is interruptible
by the delivery of a signal."  So I am hoping to reach the line marked
`###` with `result == EINTR` when I press ctrl-C or otherwise send this
process a signal. But as it stands, I do not: the program just
terminates with the usual signum-dependent message.

I presumably have to change the signal handler somehow, but how?  I tried defining `void handler(int){}` and registering  it with `signal(SIGINT, handler)`. That prevents termination of course but it doesn’t magically make `sem_wait()` interruptible—presumably there’s something different I should be doing during registration, or in the handler itself.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and macOS 10.13.6 if this makes any difference.

```
/* Welcome to `semtest.c`. Compile with::
 * 
 *     gcc semtest.c -o semtest           # Darwin
 *     gcc semtest.c -o semtest -pthread  # Linux
 * 
 * Run with::
 * 
 *     ./semtest wait
 * 
 * Terminate by either (a) sending a signal (ctrl-c or `kill`)
 * or (b) running `./semtest post`
 */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>     /* For O_* constants */
#include <sys/stat.h>  /* For S_* mode constants */
#include <unistd.h>    /* For getpid() */

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sem_t * semaphore = NULL;
    char cmd;
    int result;
    
    if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "wait")) cmd = argv[1][0];
    else if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "post")) cmd = argv[1][0];
    else return fprintf(stderr, "usage:    %s wait\n   or:    %s post", argv[0], argv[0]);
    
#   define SEMAPHORE_NAME "/test"
    
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is running with PID %d\n", argv[0], getpid());
    if(cmd == 'w')
    {
        sem_unlink(SEMAPHORE_NAME);
        semaphore = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, O_CREAT, (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR), 0);
        if(semaphore == SEM_FAILED)
            return fprintf(stderr, "failed to create/open semaphore \"%s\" - sem_open() failed with error %d\n", SEMAPHORE_NAME, errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "waiting for semaphore \"%s\"...\n", SEMAPHORE_NAME);
        errno = 0;
        
        /* signal(SIGINT, something...? );  */
        
        result = sem_wait(semaphore);
        
        /* ### Want to reach this line with result==EINTR when signal arrives */
            
        fprintf(stderr, "sem_wait() returned %d (errno is %d)\n", result, errno);
        sem_close(semaphore);
    }
    if(cmd == 'p')
    {
        semaphore = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, O_CREAT, (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR), 0);
        if(semaphore == SEM_FAILED)
            return fprintf(stderr,"failed to create/open semaphore \"%s\" - sem_open() failed with error %d\n", SEMAPHORE_NAME, errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "posting semaphore \"%s\"\n", SEMAPHORE_NAME);
        errno = 0;
        result = sem_post(semaphore);
        if(result) fprintf(stderr, "sem_post() failed with return code %d (errno is %d)\n", result, errno);
        sem_close(semaphore);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I presumably have to change the signal handler somehow, but how?* That is the case. So are you really asking how to write and set a signal handler for ctrl-c?

Comment: Read up on `sigaction()`.

Comment: You forgot to read [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [sigaction(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). You could use [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) with [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) on Linux

Comment: @kaylum Yes and no. I had in fact read signal(7) and tried registering an empty signal handler.  It merely prevented termination, didn't interrupt `sem_wait()`.  I guess I wasn't surprised that a handler that did nothing achieved nothing, so didn't think the attempt worth mentioning and assumed there was something special I needed to be *doing* in the handler.  But I had used `signal()` to register it, and I guess I hadn't appreciated the crucial difference between `signal()` and `sigaction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `signal()` function is the simplest way to handle the signal you want.

```
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

In your case, the `signum` parameter is `SIGINT` (`^C`) and the `handle` parameter is a function you need to define according the following syntax.

```
/* Type of a signal handler.  */
typedef void (*__sighandler_t) (int);
```

Declare all variables you want to access in the handler function as global.

```
#include <signal.h>

sem_t * semaphore = NULL;

void sigint_handler( int signal );

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    // (...)
    return 0;
}

void sigint_handler( int signal ) {
    // (...)
}
```

Although the `signal()` function may work, it is recommended to use the `sigaction()` function for compatibility purposes.

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
> varied historically across different versions of Linux. Avoid  its
> use: use sigaction(2) instead.

```
int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
                     struct sigaction *oldact);
```

Using `sigaction()` in the context of your program should be something like this.

```
#include <signal.h>

sem_t * semaphore = NULL;
    
void sigint_handler( int signal );
    
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct sigaction act = { 0 };
    act.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
    // (...)
    return 0;
}
    
void sigint_handler( int signal ) {
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had in fact already tried this with `signal()` and found it didn't work (on both systems it prevented termination but didn't interrupt `sem_wait()`).   Switching to `sigaction()` was the key to making it work. I think to make this answer definitive it should lead with `sigaction`, not `signal`.

Answer (score 1):

Calls only return `EINTR` if you have registered a signal handler for the signal in question.

Demo:

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   $SIG{INT} = sub { } if $ARGV[0];
   sysread(STDIN, $buf, 1) or warn $!;
   say "ok";
' 0
^C

$ echo $?
130             # Killed by SIGINT

$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   $SIG{INT} = sub { } if $ARGV[0];
   sysread(STDIN, $buf, 1) or warn $!;
   say "ok";
' 1
^CInterrupted system call at -e line 3.
ok
```

Yeah, this is Perl, but this is not a language-specific matter. You'll get the same results in C.

Yeah, this is `read`, but this is a call-specific matter. You'll get the same results for `sem_wait`.

This was just easier to write.

(`$SIG{INT} = ...` results in a call to `sigaction`, and `sysread` is a thin wrapper around `read`. Note that `$ARGV[0]` is akin to `argv[1]`.)